# Corda Distributed Notaries

Tags: corda

There used to be a demo which ran distributed notaries which ran RAFT or BFT Smart as the consensus protocol.

This demo doesn’t seem to be available anymore via the main website.

Is there any documentation/sample code for running a distributed notary service with Raft or BFT Smart?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a distributed notary sample is still available. See https://github.com/corda/corda/tree/master/samples/notary-demo.

Comment: Thank you Joel.
I have run the demo code however I am finding that the transactions are showing up in the vault of Alice and the notaries but are not showing up in the vault of Bob. When I run SELECT * FROM VAULT_STATES in Bob - there are no rows present. Shouldn't there be the same amount of row in Bob's vault as Alice's?

Comment: See https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/master/samples/notary-demo/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/notarydemo/flows/DummyIssueAndMove.kt#L32 - it looks like only Alice is listed as a participant, and not Bob, so Bob doesn't see the state.

Comment: OK. If only Alice is a participant then what is the point of the the transaction. How does it demonstrate the use of a distributed notary if it is essentially one node talking to itself? 

Why would the demo be made so simple, surely it would make more sense to show a transaction flowing from one node to another that is notarised along the way. Is there some limitation of the code that does not allow for this? If not, would it be possible to please advise how to adjust the code to send a transaction from Alice to Bob? Thanks.

Comment: There are already many examples of transactions involving multiple parties. See https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example/blob/release-V3/kotlin-source/src/main/kotlin/com/example/flow/ExampleFlow.kt for an example. The notarisation approach doesn't affect these flows.